# android how to mount android img

Tags: android, linux

How to mount android immage file on linux .

first ,I use mount ,and met error bellow:
sudo mount -o loop system.img system-img

mount: /smb/system-img: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

I have check my image format by file
file system.img

system.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data, UUID=fd508505-0ab2-4775-a1b6-42b1198db78d (extents) (large files) (huge files)

simg2img system.img system.img-ex

Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Failed to read sparse file

method I have try
first: sudo e2fsck -f system.img
second : sudo mount system.img system-img  -o loop -t ext2

the error info is not change

infos I have explorered

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315063/mount-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215866/how-to-unpack-repack-system-img-of-android-rom?newreg=c5a44819e20d403585f68c51bafcef11

method to mount android image

Comment: What android image do you try to mount? Where does it come from?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Robert. I want mount system.img

I compile it myself . It run OK,if  I flash it to device

My current task involves reducing the size of the image, including the removal of certain files. Because it involves the packaging process, it is more efficient to inspect through mounting compared to flash to the device.

Comment: Use `kpartx` or `losetup`